# My Firebase isn't correctly assigning a FCM Token to my device, but everything else is working correctly

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am having quite a lot of trouble right now. I was trying to get push notifications to work on my app, and everything was going well until I realized that my firebase had the wrong bundleID.

I could use firebase auth, realtime database, and firestore, but notifications and firebase messaging would not work. At this time, each user would have their fcmToken stored under their uid in firestore. Everything was working well. To fix the issue, I created a new firebase with the right bundle id.

The auth, realtime, and firestore are all working perfectly fine in my current app. However, the fcm token is no longer registering when a user opens the app. I'm using the same app delegate code as before, yet it's not showing up under each user in Firestore. What is weird is that in the console I see that that the user is being given an FCM Token and is being authenticated for notifications, but it's just not working in firebase.

I will attach pictures of my app delegate and console. I have linked an APNs key to the Cloud Messaging in Project Settings. My XCode has all the required things set up as well. I am running the code on the iOS XCode simulator, and like I said, it was working perfectly before and I wouldnt have changed it if not for the incorrect bundleID.

What I see is that the app goes into didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken in app delegate, but it doesn't go into didReceiveRegistrationToken which is really strange. Anyways, I'll attach the image with the app delegate and the console so you can see what I'm working with here. Let me know if you need to see anything else.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
public var partyAccount = false
public var launchedBefore = false
public var authenticated = false
public var user_address = ""
public var currentDate = ""
public var votesLabel = 0
public var barName = ""
public var UID = ""
public var publicOrPriv = true
public var maxPeople = 0
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate,
 UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
     [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:
         [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { success, _ in
            guard success else {
            }   return
            print("Notification authorization granted.")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
        }   }   application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        // Check if the app has a registered device token for remote
         notifications
    if let token = application.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types {
        print("Device has registered for remote notifications.")
} else {
        print("Device has not registered for remote notifications.")
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    UID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "UID") ?? ""
    barName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "barName") ?? ""
    partyAccount = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "partyAccount")
    launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
    authenticated = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "authenticated")
    user_address = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "user_address") ??
     "user"
    votesLabel = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "votesLabel")
    currentDate = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "currentDate") ?? ""
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    let newDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    if newDate != currentDate {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(5, forKey: "votesLabel")
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newDate, forKey: "currentDate")
} else {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newDate, forKey: "currentDate")
    }
    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let uid = currentUser.uid
        print("User UID:", uid)
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(uid, forKey: "UID")
} else {
        print("No user is currently signed in.")
    }
return true
}
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken
 fcmToken: String?) {
    // This method is called when the app successfully registers for FCM
     notifications.
    // Store the FCM token in Firestore
    print("Received FCM token:", fcmToken ?? "No token available")
    if let fcmToken = fcmToken, let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let uid = currentUser.uid

        let userRef =
         Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid)
        let data: [String: Any] = [
        ]   "fcmToken": fcmToken,
        userRef.setData(data, merge: true) { error in
            if let error = error {
                // Handle the error
                print("Error storing FCM token in Firestore:
                 \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                // Success!
                print("FCM token stored in Firestore.")
            }
} }
}
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
 willPresent notification: UNNotification) async
    -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions{
        // Customize how the notification should be presented when the app
         is in the foreground.
        // For example, you can show an alert, play a sound, or set the
         badge number.
        return[[.alert, .sound, .badge]]
    }
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive
 response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler
 completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // Handle the notification data and perform appropriate actions.
        // For example, you can open a specific screen in your app based
         on the notification data.
        // Get the notification payload data
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Process the data as needed
        // For example, you can extract information from userInfo
         dictionary and navigate to a specific screen.
        // Call the completion handler after handling the notification
        completionHandler()
    }
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // This method is called when the app successfully registers for
     remote notifications.

    // You can send the device token to your server if needed.
    // Convert the device token to a string representation (hexadecimal
     format)
    let tokenString = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0)
     }.joined()
    // Print the device token for testing
    print("Device Token: \(tokenString)")
    // Pass the device token to Firebase Cloud Messaging
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
 didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    // This method is called when there is an error in registering for
     remote notifications.
    // Handle the error as needed.
    print("Failed to register for remote notifications:
     \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting
 connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options:
 UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene
with.
    let launchCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "launchCount")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(launchCount + 1, forKey: "launchCount")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration",
     sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions
 sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not
     running, this will be called shortly after
     application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the
     discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}
func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) ->
Bool {

} return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
}
```

[here is the console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdqr7.png)

I've tried cleaning the build folder, resetting the APNs token, and rewriting the code. But none of this worked because as you can see the device still has a token registered to it, it's just not registering as a FCM Token.